# Add scroll view in sliding Drawer

Tags: android, scrollbar, slidingdrawer

I have used `SlidingDrawer` in my application. Now I want to add scroll view in it. I have tried to do so but it gives me error which says sliding drawer must have specified dimensions.
Can any one help me for that.

Comment: Paste the exact error message you get.

Answer (score 1):

For a **scrollview**, you must type at the least :

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent or wrap_content or your value" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent or wrap_content or your value" >
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set layout_width and layout_height as Yann MASOCH says to get rid of that error message.

Also remember to set the id as id/content in the scrollview instead of the linearLayout in order for the slidingdrawer to work with scroll. Here is an example of the SlidingDrawer with scroll:

```
<SlidingDrawer
 android:id="@+id/drawer"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:handle="@+id/handle"
 android:content="@+id/content">

 <Button
     android:id="@id/handle"
     android:layout_width="88dip"
     android:layout_height="44dip"
     android:background="@drawable/btn_blue"
     android:text="help"
     android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
 <ScrollView
  android:id="@id/content"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">

(other TextViews etc)

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</SlidingDrawer>
```